# How to modify an encapsulated library in Java?

Tags: java

I am using a generator for my project. Problem is now I need to modify this library's some methods according to my needs.

Generator class is final so I can't create a new class that extends it. Also putlast method is private.

Is there a way to solve this problem or I need to remove this library?

My main method;

```
generator.setFlowProperty(myProperty);
```

Library classes;

```
public final class Generator{

   public Builder setFlowProperty(Property property) {

       putLast("flowProperty", property.toCustomString());

       ....
   }


   private Builder putLast(String name, String value) {
       ....
   }
}


public final class Property{

   public String toCustomString(){
       return "a" + prop;  // I want to modify this and return "b"+ instead of "a"+.
   }

}
```

Comment: The purpose of these `final` is to disallow this practice, so how do you think you would be able to do it ?

Comment: You could submit a patch for the library if it is open source.

Comment: @Markus Yes it is open source. I will try it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you can inherit final class. I suppose library author made Generator class not for overriding. Anyway you can create your own class with logic you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to override only a few functionalties of the library and leave most of them as they are, you can create a class that wraps the library class, only modifying the desired behaviours. So, the main purpose of this class will be to serve as a proxy before the library class, except when you want to modify some behaviour.